# Regex to get all characters before "|"

Tags: regex

How can I get the string before the character "|" using regular expressions?

For example, I have "data1|data2" and I want to return "data1".

Comment: What language? What have you tried?

Comment: You have `data1|data2`, I have `|data1|data2` and we both want `data1` because we see that _data1_ is what is needed. So, what does the pipe have to do with it ??

Answer (score -1):

You want this regex: `^.+?(?=\|)`

- `^` beginning of line
- `.+?` one or more characters, as few as possible
- `(?=)` forward look ahead assertion; make sure you can see the enclosed pattern
- `\|` a literal `|` character

Comment: Why not simply `^[^|]*` ? Using a lookahead in this context seems overkill.

Comment: @Aaron Good point. Post your own answer and I'll upvote it as also correct.

Comment: I'd rather find a good duplicate than post an answer, there's no way this isn't already answered in other questions.

Comment: @Aaron Good man.

Comment: What if it is not single character `|` but part of a word `__dec`?